# Replacing Oracle newline characters in a .NET string

Tags: vb.net, winforms, oracle, oracle9i

I'm using the Oracle command dbms_output.get_line to retrieve output from a stored procedure.  Once my code runs the command, I'm retrieving the results through a buffer string, 32000 bytes long.

Inevitably, this string will have Oracle line breaks **(chr(10) and chr(13))** in it that I'd like to replace with **Environment.NewLine** so I can display the output in a standard Winforms textbox.

Here is the code I've been using - I don't recall exactly where I got the Oracle command right now, but if I find it, I'll add the link.

```
Dim cmdGetOutput As New OracleCommand("declare " & _
" l_line varchar2(255); " & _
" l_done number; " & _
" l_buffer long; " & _
"begin " & _
" loop " & _
" exit when length(l_buffer)+255 > :maxbytes OR l_done =1; " & _
" dbms_output.get_line( l_line, l_done ); " & _
" l_buffer := l_buffer || l_line || chr(10); " & _
" end loop; " & _
" :done := l_done; " & _
" :buffer := l_buffer; " & _
"end;", cnOracle)

cmdGetOutput.Parameters.Add("maxbytes", OracleType.Int16)
cmdGetOutput.Parameters("maxbytes").Value = 32000
cmdGetOutput.Parameters.Add("done", OracleType.Int16)
cmdGetOutput.Parameters("done").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
cmdGetOutput.Parameters.Add("buffer", OracleType.LongVarChar, 32000)
cmdGetOutput.Parameters("buffer").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

Dim strOutput As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim intStatus As Integer = 0
Try
   While True
      cmdGetOutput.ExecuteNonQuery()
      strOutput.Add(cmdGetOutput.Parameters("buffer").Value)
      If cmdGetOutput.Parameters("done").Value = 1 Then
         Exit While
      End If
   End While
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
   For ixLines as Integer = 0 to strOutput.Count - 1
      txtOutput.Text = txtOutput.Text & strOutput(ixLines)
   Next
End Try
```

When I run this, txtOutput will have box characters in places where newlines should be.

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, that code shouldn't even compile.  You can not assign a List(of String) to a TextBox.Text property.

second, the String class defines a Replace(searchstring, replacementstring) method.

Comment: I had thought that Chr(10) and Chr(13) in Oracle were different than in .NET, but I was wrong.